# Image not Working on PDF rendered page

Tags: visualforce, pdf, rerender, images

I created visual force that converts the page to PDF as below

**VF Page**

```
<apex:page controller="PDFGenerationTest" lightningStylesheets="false" renderAs="pdf" showChat="false" showHeader="false" standardStylesheets="false" applyBodyTag="false" applyHtmlTag="false" >
     <apex:outputText value="{!emailBody}" escape="false"/>
</apex:page>
```

**Apex:**

```
public class PDFGenerationTest {    
    public String emailBody {get;set;}
  public PDFGenerationTest(){
  logoUrl = 'https://img1a.flixcart.com/www/linchpin/fk-cp-zion/img/fk-plus_3b0baa.png';

  emailBody ='<div style="display: flex; padding-bottom: 1.5rem;">  <div style="width: 50%;float: left;"> <img src=' + logoUrl  +' style="width:100%; max-width:300px;"></div>';
}
}
```

I have an external image that I'm trying to render in a PDF. Image displaying PDF as below.

[image]

Can you please help me on this to resolve this issue

Answer (score 1):

Probably it happened as you set all the html in the outputtext. It indeed set to not escape html tags, but I think with too complex html it won't work. You should img tag like:

```
<img src="specific-url"/>
```

if you need to generated dynamic url, then in the controller generat only the url, not the whole html:

```
<img src="{!myURLString}"/>
```

Comment: Tried still the same issue <div style="width: 50%;float: left;"> <img src="{!logoUrl}" style="width:100%; max-width:300px;" /></div>

Comment: i also tried it and got similar broken image. It does worked after I added 'https://img1a.flixcart.com' into Remote Site Settings. Seems like requirement from SF security side.